# On button click change div width, on next button click return it as it was?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, video

```
<div class="video-embeds" style="margin-top: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
    width: 950px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
">
<div class="video-embed" style="margin-top: 0px;">
<?php

$url1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'video_play' , true );
$search     = '#(.*?)(?:href="https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch?.*?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*#x';
$replace    = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2';
$url        = preg_replace($search,$replace,$url1);

?>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo $url; ?>" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
</div>
```

This one should be changed:

```
<div class="video-embeds" style="margin-top: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
    width: 950px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
">
```

to:

```
<div class="video-embeds" style="margin-top: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
">
```

As you can see its for changing div to go to full width parent div or 100%, or to be 950px (depend on media screen size, its variable), and it should be by button.

What is easiest solution for this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function changec() {
       var xDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('video-embeds');

       if (xDiv.style.width == '') 
           xDiv.style.width = '950px'
       else 
           xDiv.style.width = '100%'
}
</script>

<div id="menu" onclick="changec()">&#8801;</div>
```

Tried this script, but variable `xDiv.style.width = '950px'` can't be constant as css changes due to responsive css, and also onclick won't return it.

Comment: Where is your script?

Comment: Sorry. I just added it.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use Javascript, and call the Function by the ID of the element, 
to change the settings use a if-clause inside of the function:

```
var element = document.getElementById('divid'); 

if (element.style.width == '900px') element.style.width= '100%' else element.style.width = '900px' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the status of your `<div>`, if it is clicked or not using class.

```
function changec() {
       var xDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('video-embeds')[0];

       if (this.classList.contains('clicked'))  {
           xDiv.style.width = '950px'
           this.classList.remove('clicked')
       } else {
           xDiv.style.width = '100%'
           this.classList.add('clicked')
       }
}
```

Or you can play with `boolean` flag

```
var clicked = false;
function changec() {
       var xDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('video-embeds')[0];

       if (!clicked)  {
           xDiv.style.width = '950px'
           clicked = true;
       } else {
           xDiv.style.width = '100%'
           clicked = false;
       }
}
```

Comment: Second one works with getElementById, but I have 3 variables for width, one is 950px;, other 750px; and third is 600px; I tried elseif, but is says undefined.

Comment: So play with 3 classes value